# Route53 record targeting other hosted zone

Tags: amazon-ecs, aws-cloudmap, aws-route53

Given two hosted zones:

1. `mydomain.com`
2. `someapp.` (Managed by ECS/Cloud Map)

and given a service registered under:

`service1.someapp.` (Managed by ECS/Cloud Map)

Can you define a record like:

1. `service1.mydomain.com`, or
2. `service2.someapp.mydomain.com`

targeting the service mapped by `service1.someapp`?

Comment: The ECS/Cloud Map domain is only going to be resolvable by things running inside your VPC. Are you planning to only have your VPC resources look up the `service1.mydomain.com` address?

Comment: I get your point. I'm trying to publicly expose that service without using a load balancer. The ECS task runs in a public subnet and it has a public IP. So if possible, I would route from service1.mydomain.com to the mapped name. I don't want to make a route53 record mapping the public IP directly, because I may have multiple ECS tasks replicas, and generally speaking tasks IPs are ephemeral

Comment: You should check if Cloud Map even places the public IP of the task in Route53. I think it's going to be placing the private IP in there, which will be even less helpful for your specific issue. If you want an ECS task to be exposed publicly, a load balancer really is the best solution.

Comment: Yes I normally use the load balancer on top, my objective now is to figure out if I can avoid the LB and to work wih ECS/Cloud Map/Route53 only.

Comment: The documentation says CloudMap supports public domain names: https://aws.amazon.com/cloud-map/faqs/ so you need to look into configuring CloudMap appropriately for a public domain name. Just pointing your public domain to a private CloudMap domain will not work outside of the VPC.